# Measure screen brightness using Spyder3 software?

Tags: display-calibration, spyder3

There is one feature I miss in Datacolors spyder3 calibration software:

To be able to calibrate screen brightness to a defined value like 100cd/m².

Right now the datacolor just says "adjust the brightness to a level comfortable for you". Well, duh, I did not buy a calibration device to adjust my display "to my comfort", but to a usable, repeatable value.

From Eizo's ColorNavigator software I'm used to set the brightness I want to calibrate to in the software, then calibration will measure and adjust accordingly.

Without proper display brightness the brightness of prints will be off, and the prints being what I see on the display is what calibration is about.

So: Is it possible in DataColors software to measure and adjust screen brightness? Or maybe at least to measure and display the screen brightness?

Comment: use a lightmeter? ;)

Comment: Heh, no, really, the Spyder3 hardware can do this with the ColorNavigator software, so it should be possible with the DataColor Software, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new version of Spyder3Elite, v4.0, supports brightness, as well as a bunch of other measurements and software-based adjustments. It is far richer calibration software than the Sypder3Elite 3.x software. An upgrade costs $99, but it is pretty worth it.

http://spyder.datacolor.com/product-pu-s3e4_UPGRADE.php

Comment: Duh, I only got the Spyder3pro and use the DataColor Software only for my notebook - no way to achieve this without shelling out for an upgrade?

Comment: It looks like the upgrade is actually only $19... I guess they dropped the price. For that price, I would totally get it. Its got a ton of features, nice graphing, multi-screen comparisons of statistics, etc.

Comment: It's also free if you bought the thing in 2010.

Comment: Aye, thats how I got it myself. I just purchased the Sypder3Studio SR, and got the upgraded Sypder3Elite software for free.

Comment: Dang - so using Spyder3 pro software I can't really fully calibrate my monitor? For full calibration I need the elite version? Sounds a bit like a ripoff to me :(

Comment: Well, you can fully "calibrate" your screen. If you want other capabilities, like luminance evenness measurements, brightness metering, etc., you need the new software. You bought the Spyder3 Pro, which is EXTREMELY cheap for a calibrator, and a pretty good deal. Given that the upgrade is $20, even after that, you still get a REALLY good deal on an excellent calibrator. To contrast, the screen calibration package from X-Rite costs about $1500.

Comment: Oh, $19 is quite a difference from $99 - I guess I'm a bit surprised because it does work with the Colornavigator software.